# How do I get stack call information in an x64 program?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86-64, backtrace

- I found a way to get the information of the stack call in an x86 program. The code is not difficult to understand:

```
#ifdef X86
void TestGetCallStack_X86()
{
    std::cout << "Call -> TestGetCallStack_X86" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "***************************************" << std::endl;
    DWORD _ebp, _esp;
    __asm mov _ebp, ebp
    __asm mov _esp, esp

    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < CALLSTACK_NUM; index++) {
        void* pAddr = (void*)ULongToPtr(*(((DWORD*)ULongToPtr(_ebp)) + 1));
        if (!pAddr)
            return;

        IMAGEHLP_LINE64 Line;
        Line.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(Line);
        memset(&Line, 0, sizeof(Line));
        DWORD Offset = 0;
        if (fnSymGetLineFromAddr64(s_Process, (DWORD64)pAddr, &Offset, &Line))
        {
            std::cout << index << " [" << pAddr << "]";

            std::cout << "  File Name:" << Line.FileName << "  " << "Line Count:" << Line.LineNumber << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            if (error == 487)
            {
                OutputDebugString(TEXT("No debug info in current module\n"));
            }
            else if (error == 126)
            {
                OutputDebugString(TEXT("Debug info in current module has not loaded\n"));
            }
            else
            {
                OutputDebugString(TEXT("SymGetLineFromAddr64 failed\n"));
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        _ebp = *(DWORD*)ULongToPtr(_ebp);
        if (_ebp == 0 || 0 != (_ebp & 0xFC000000) || _ebp < _esp)
            break;
    }
    std::cout << "***************************************" << std::endl;
}
#endif // X86
```

[run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZFXc.png)

---

- I wrote an x64 version and found that MSVC for x64 does't support inline assembly.
- I try to write a .asm file and load the function in C++ code. but it does't work. (Actually I'm not good at Assembly language)
- I found many ways. So far, I have used the `_ReturnAddress` to achieve.

```
void TestGetCallStack_X64()
{
    void* pAddr = _ReturnAddress();
    if (!pAddr)
        return;
    std::cout << "0" << "\t" << pAddr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Use GetLineFromAddress64:" << std::endl;

    IMAGEHLP_LINE64 Line;
    Line.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(Line);
    memset(&Line, 0, sizeof(Line));
    DWORD Offset = 0;
    if (fnSymGetLineFromAddr64(s_Process, (DWORD64)pAddr, &Offset, &Line))
    {
        std::cout << "File Name:" << Line.FileName << "\t" << "Line Count:" << Line.LineNumber << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //Can not find...
    }
}
```

[Run Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqp0x.png)

- But this way cannot fully display the information of the stack call. How should I achieve the same effect as the x86 version？

---

PS: I can't understand the condition of break in x86's Code. Can anyone answer, Please! Thank you first.

```
//what's the mean that <_ebp & 0xFC000000>

if (_ebp == 0 || 0 != (_ebp & 0xFC000000) || _ebp < _esp)
```

Comment: `0 != (_ebp & 0xFC000000)` appears to be testing for values that don't look like valid frame pointers.  Apparently 32-bit Windows programs have their stack in the low 26 bits of virtual address space, so the `0xFC...` (`0b11111100...`) bits won't be set.

Comment: nice. I got it, Thanks!!!   :)